# Copying local production build for to production server

Tags: angular

Our angular application build size is around 38MB (size of dist directory), and source-map's build size is 1.6MB. Our AWS instance configuration is:
**Ram**: 4GB.
**OS**: Ubuntu.
 But when we build it on the server for production, CPU usage reaches 100%, sometimes it takes 1/2hr to complete the build, sometimes it can even fail. We have two possible option for this problem:
**1**. While creating the production build, we set the **AOT and build optimizer to false**. However, it will affect our application performance during runtime.
**2.** We are thinking of building the production build locally from our system, then copy the build to the server (it will be done through CI/CD tools). However, developers will be using a different OS. Some will be using Windows, some will be using Linux or Mac.
1. Will there be any issue with such an approach?
2. Is there any better way to solve such a problem?

Comment: Maybe you should tackle the root of your issue, which is the size of your application ?

Comment: the 38MB includes the assets which contain the images and JSON which we use on the front end

Comment: Assets aren't included in the bundles. They're kept apart. They don't impact your application performance.

Comment: That the point. 38MB is the size of dist directory(not the bundle size) which includes assets.

Comment: Yeah well your issue isn't coming from there anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your application production build should not be 38MB.
You **HAVE TO** set the build optimizer to true, it will reduce a lot your build size.

It looks like you have some performances issues, and it will be hard to build your application in a CI Platform (GitlabCI, CircleCI, etc) because they limit the build time or the performances.

Before, you should really fix theses performances issues.
If you still have performances problems with build, you can change node memory limit :
`./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --max-old-space-size`

You can find more informations, directly on the Angular Documentation : https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: build size is 38MB including the assets. Inside it, we have images and json ( around 10MB) which we use on the front end.